# Search by node content nokgiri::XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

How can I search by content of a node using nokogiri::XML ?

Lets say I have the following xml

```
<parts>
  <part>
    <name>foo</name>
    <madein>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <country>XYZ</country>
    </madein>
  </part>
  <part>
    <name>foo</name>
    <madein>
      <city>PQR</city>
      <country>XYZ</country>
    </madein>
  </part>
  <part>
    <name>foo</name>
    <madein>
      <city>ABC</city>
      <country>XYZ</country>
    </madein>
  </part>
</parts>
```

And I want to get all parts for which /madein/city is ABC. What is the best way to get the parts nodes ?

I am using nokogiri gem.

Thanks

Comment: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath is query language for XML, and is very flexible.

To get you started:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse( xml_string )
parts_from_abc = doc.xpath( '/parts/part[madein/city="ABC"]' )
```

As bdares suggested in the comments, if you want to do more, take a look at the [tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials).